# Can I place functions within interpolated strings and if so how

Tags: c#

Consider the following code snippet;

```
 foreach (var row in VtlDxGrid.GetSelectedRowHandles())
        {
            string name = Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "ContactName"));
            string hn = Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "HouseName"));
            string street1 = Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "StreetLine1"));
            string street2 = Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "StreetLine2"));
            string pt = Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "PostalTown"));
            string pc = Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "PostCode"));
            string country = Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "Country"));

            SelectedAddress = $"{name} {hn ?? ":"} : {street1} : {street2 ?? ":"}  {pt} : {pc} : {country}";
        }
```

HouseName, StreetLine2 and Country could contain null values.  I need to end up with a string that contains values separated by a colon (with no colon at the end should county be null).

The above works to an extent in so far as I happen to know that HouseName and StreetLine2 are null. However Country is also null in this instance and I end up with a colon at the end.

Can I place functions within interpolated strings or should I be looking to approach this from a different angle?

EDIT

in the current example I amending up with ;

Jim's Fish Shop  : Harold Road :   HASTINGS : TN45 6QR :

I need to allow for the fact that all three of the fields that could be null might not be, and any conceivable variations of null or a value to end up with a string that contains all of the fields that have a value separated by a colon.

Comment: What are you expecting?  You're ending the string with a colon and then a null string (which shows as empty in this case).

Comment: Interpolations can contain arbitrary expressions.

Comment: @Archer I've added an edit which I hope makes things clearer.

Comment: You can do what you want in one line, but honestly it will be ugly as sin and too much effort for anyone else to figure out what it was and why you'd done it (would require ternary operators within string interpolation - UUUUGGGHH!!!)  Just make it readable - maybe use a function to return `": { value }"` when value != null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a different approach. Instead of reading those cells into separate variables, I would add to a list and then use string.Join like so

```
List<string> theList = new List<string>();

theList.Add("The name");
theList.Add(null);
theList.Add("stree1 line 1");
theList.Add(null);
theList.Add("postal town");
theList.Add("postal code");
theList.Add(null);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(":", theList.Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))))
```

in your case it would become like

```
List<string> addressInfoList = new List<string>();

addressInfoList.Add(Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "ContactName")));
addressInfoList.Add(Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "HouseName")));
addressInfoList.Add(Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "StreetLine1")));
addressInfoList.Add(Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "StreetLine2")));
addressInfoList.Add(Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "PostalTown")));
addressInfoList.Add(Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "PostCode")));
addressInfoList.Add(Convert.ToString(VtlDxGrid.GetCellValue(row, "Country")));


Console.WriteLine(string.Join(":", addressInfoList.Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))));
```

Comment: Thank you, simple, but above all easily readable and understandable to anyone who should read it or use it at a later date.